# Inline IF with no ELSE

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to update the property of objects in a `List` based on a 0/1 pattern in a `string`.

```
//list.length is always == pattern.length
string pattern = Convert.ToString(8, 2);
var listWithDeleted = list.Select((s, index) => pattern[index] == '1' ? s.IsDeleted == true : s.IsDeleted = s.IsDeleted);
```

I'm a bit sad about the `else`-clause `: s.IsDeleted = s.IsDeleted` of my inlined `if`-statement. I understand inlined `if` needs an `else`-clause as it needs to return a value but it made me wonder if there may be a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: Won't `pattern[0]` always equal true and anything else always equal false?  Could you replace `pattern[index] == '1'` with `index == 0`?

Comment: I think there is an issue with the original code.  If I try to compile with the assignment operator in the third expression of the ternary operator, I get this error: "An expression tree may not contain an assignment operator".  Do you mean, `list.Select((s, index) => pattern[index] == '1' ? s.IsDeleted == true : s.IsDeleted == s.IsDeleted);`?

Comment: @WyattEarp The original compiles fine for me, albeit with a warning about assigning to the same variable.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Ah, that makes sense.  I was using LinqPad to an entity, but if I just use linq-to-objects it compiles...

Comment: @iggy I'm still a bit confused though, about what the code actually does.  I don't see a case where it differs from `list.Select(s => s.IsDeleted);`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use:

```
s.IsDeleted = pattern[index] == '1' || s.IsDeleted
```

If it's already `true`, it will stay `true` regardless of `pattern[index]`, otherwise it will only become true if `pattern[index]` is `'1'`

Comment: I'm wondering if this is actually correct now I've looked more closely at the OP's code.  It doesn't actually change the value of `s.IsDeleted` at any point, whereas mine would.  @Iggy - can you confirm if this is what you're after?  If not, I'll delete...

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution

```
s.IsDeleted = pattern[index] == '1' ?  true : s.IsDeleted
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter and only apply the operation where you need to. You wouldn't write the `foreach` equivalent in a ternary like that, so I don't see why you should do it that way in LINQ either.

```
list.Where((s, index) => pattern[index] == '1').Select(s => s.IsDeleted = true);
```

Note that it's strange to mutate in the `Select` (compounded by the strangeness of mutating in a ternary); in this case your `listWithDeleted` actually returns an `IEnumerable<bool>` (the result of the ternary) which seems odd. It would be better to use `List.ForEach` or your own `void` returning `IEnumerable.ForEach` extension to make intent a little clearer.